# kotlin-gradle plugin auto configure error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

[Module build.gradle code and file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JGUW.png)

[Project build.gradle and buildscript code, and reported error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBXSL.png)

Just getting started with kotlin for android development here. After converting MainActivity to .kt, the kotlin-gradle plugin needs to be configured. IntelliJ offers to do it automatically, but fails with the error:
Cannot find build.gradle for module app.
I know I can configure it myself, but why cant intelliJ find the build.gradle files, they are in the project that was automatically generated by intelliJ itself. Do I have something configured incorrectly?
Any help or insight is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please add your project modules & files layout? And probably your buildscripts content would also make things more clear.

Comment: I have added some screens to hopefully make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

---

Seems that you are using Idea 2016.1. There is a bug in your tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11593

Answer (score 0):

Download the Maven repo from SDK manager, then try to reconfigure the kotlin again.

Comment: Downloading the maven repository did not fix the problem. Also changing repos from jcenter to maven in build.gradle yields the same result.